# CSS: content scaling in parent div

Tags: html, css, famo.us

I'm using famo.us for rendering surfaces contaning HTML. I want the HTML content to scale with transformations on the surface. For example a "polaroid" rendering with picture and name:

[image: Famo.us html tester]

HTML:

```
<div id="contentdiv" style="width:164px; height:199px; background-color: aqua; border: dashed">
    <div class="polaroid">
        <img class="img-responsive"  src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7197720/www/Serge.jpg'>
        <p>Serge</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.polaroid {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; /* width 144px, both sides 10px border */
}

.polaroid img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2.4vw solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
       -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
}

.polaroid p {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    font: 400 1vw 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    color: #888;
}
```

I just don't get the CSS in a shape that when I enlarge or minimize the div, the content scales with it. To test scaling within a div I created a simple test harness with the example I try to implement. See http://codepen.io/svdoever/pen/raGjrZ. Problem is the scaling/positiong of fonts and that borders should scale on resize, so smaller border on smaller size.

[image: Scaling suboptimal]

My first question is: is it possible to write html/css that scales correctly with the parent container? Should work for images, fonts, margins etc. Is there a solution for my example?

My second question is: is it possible to make the html/css responsive, so show less/more content based on the size of the container element.

My third question is: what are the best practices for writing this type of html/css.

EDIT: I found blogpost http://blog.sathomas.me/post/zooming-html-content-with-css-scale-transform, but don't really understand the approach yet...

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for what you have done in your codepin using [Famo.us](http://famo.us). I have created an example, but will not include all the features of your codepen, but it will give you a start for dynamic css in Famo.us

#### Answer to first question:

It is possible to write css that will scale proportionately in your event handlers.

**[Example jsBin of code below](http://jsbin.com/siyamu/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  mainContext.setPerspective(1000);

  var splash = new Surface({ content: 'Famo.us Application'});

  mainContext.add(splash);

  var proportion = 1;
  var orig = 144;
  var min = 100;
  var max = 1440;
  var widthLabel = new Surface({
    content: 'Width',
    size: [true, true]
  });
  var widthSlider = new InputSurface({
    type: 'range',
    value: orig,
    attributes: {
      min: min,
      max: max
    }
  });
  var heightLabel = new Surface({
    content: 'Height',
    size: [true, true]
  });
  var heightSlider = new InputSurface({
    type: 'range',
    value: orig,
    attributes: {
      min: min,
      max: max
    }
  });

  function _changeProportions() {
    var value = widthSlider.getValue();
    polaroidMod.setSize([value,value]);
    proportion = value/orig ;
    polaroidText.setOptions({properties: {fontSize: Math.round(proportion) + 'em'}});
    image.setOptions({          
      properties: {
        border: Math.round(proportion*10) + 'px solid #fff',
        borderBottom: Math.round(proportion * 1.5) + 'em solid #fff',
        boxShadow: Math.round(proportion*3) + 'px ' + Math.round(proportion*3) + 'px ' + Math.round(proportion*3) + 'px #777'
      }
    });
    polaroidText.mod.setTransform(Transform.translate(0,-Math.round(proportion*15), 0.002));
  }
  widthSlider.on('input', function(e){
    var slider = e.target;
    heightSlider.setValue(slider.value);
    _changeProportions(slider.value);
  });
  heightSlider.on('input', function(e){
    var slider = e.target;
    widthSlider.setValue(slider.value);
    _changeProportions();
  });
  var widthNode = mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    size: [200, 40],
    transform: Transform.translate(0,20, 0.001)
  }));
  var heightNode = mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    size: [200, 40],
    transform: Transform.translate(210,20, 0.001)
  }));
  widthNode.add(widthLabel);
  widthNode.add(widthSlider);
  heightNode.add(heightLabel);
  heightNode.add(heightSlider);

  var polaroidMod = new Modifier({
    size: [orig, orig],
    transform: Transform.translate(10,70, 0.001),
    proportions: [1, 1]
  });
  var polaroidNode = mainContext.add(polaroidMod);

  var polaroid = new ContainerSurface({
    size:[undefined, undefined]
  });
  var image = new ImageSurface({
    size:[undefined, true],
    content: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7197720/www/Serge.jpg',
    properties: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      border: Math.round(proportion*10) + 'px solid #fff',
      borderBottom: Math.round(proportion) + 'em solid #fff',
      boxShadow: '3px 3px 3px #777'
    }
  });
  polaroidNode.add(polaroid);
  polaroid.add(image);

  polaroidText = new Surface({
    size: [true, true],
    content: 'Serge',
    properties: {
      font: "400 "+ Math.round(proportion) +"em 'Kaushan Script', cursive",
      color: '#888',
      fontSize: Math.round(proportion) + 'em'
    }
  });
  polaroidText.mod = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0],
    align: [0.5, 1],
    transform: Transform.translate(0,-15, 0.002)
  }); 
  var textNode = polaroidNode.add(polaroidText.mod);
  textNode.add(polaroidText);
```

#### Answer to second question:

Yes, you could make it responsive within your transition event handlers as in the example.

#### Answer to third question:

Best practice in my opinion is based on use case, but you can see that styling can be dynamic during transitions without using a style sheet file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hoped for a solution where I could handle everything in the html and css, that is why I made this test harness. Writing it out completely in "famo.us" code will make it very hard to make new content to be used in a famo.us application quickly. You need famo.us knowledge, instead of html/css knowledge only... I will try out your approach in my code now, but I'm still hoping for a html/css only solution.

Comment: I understand you wanted the mixed solution, but it will cause you some pain.  Trying to manage transitions in famous content using css outside of famo.us is going to cause you issues. Good luck and happy coding.